# how to upload file into googlecloud through java

Tags: java

I want to upload a file into bucket in  Google cloud storage Api.  But when i run the servelet class  then  it successfully deployed and it shows the output  in browser like  " Now see here your file content, that you have uploaded on storage..
File uploading done" .

But the problem is the servelet class will not establish the connection to Google cloud storage.And the file will not uploaded into bucket.Once check

the code and  give suggestion to how to connect to bucket with this source code.

```
 public class TestCloudStorageServlet extends HttpServlet{

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private StorageService storage = new StorageService();
 private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;
 private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestCloudStorageServlet.class.getName()); 
 @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
   log.info(this.getServletInfo()+" Servlets called....");
     resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().println("Now see here your file content, that you have uploaded on    storage..");

  ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
     System.out.println(upload);
    FileItemIterator iter;
   try {
    iter = upload.getItemIterator(req);

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
   FileItemStream item = iter.next();
   String fileName = item.getName();
   String mime = item.getContentType();

   storage.init(fileName, mime);
   InputStream is = item.openStream();

   byte[] b = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
   int readBytes = is.read(b, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
   while (readBytes != -1) {
       storage.storeFile(b, readBytes);
       readBytes = is.read(b, 0, readBytes);
   }

   is.close();
   storage.destroy();

    resp.getWriter().println("File uploading done");

     //resp.getWriter().println("READ:" + storage.readTextFileOnly(fileName));

                     log.info(this.getServletName()+" ended....");        

      }
     } 
       catch (FileUploadException e) {
           System.out.println("FileUploadException::"+e.getMessage());
         log.severe(this.getServletName()+":FileUploadException::"+e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (Exception e) {
    log.severe(this.getServletName()+":Exception::"+e.getMessage());
         System.out.println("Exception::"+e.getMessage());
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
       }
```

my StorageService class for uploading file.

```
       public class StorageService {

         public static final String BUCKET_NAME = "mybucketname";  

        private FileWriteChannel writeChannel = null;
            FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
        private OutputStream os = null;
        private static final Logger log =            Logger.getLogger(StorageService.class.getName());

       public void init(String fileName, String mime) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("Storage service:init() method:  file name:"+fileName+"  and                mime:"+mime);
     log.info("Storage service:init() method:  file name:"+fileName+" and mime:"+mime);
        log.info("test.."); 
   GSFileOptionsBuilder builder = new GSFileOptionsBuilder()
        .setAcl("public_read")
        .setBucket(BUCKET_NAME)
        .setKey(fileName)
        .setMimeType(mime);
   log.info("test..");
 AppEngineFile writableFile = fileService.createNewGSFile(builder.build());
 boolean lock = true;
 writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(writableFile, lock);
    os = Channels.newOutputStream(writeChannel);
      }

        public void storeFile(byte[] b, int readSize) throws Exception {
      os.write(b, 0, readSize);
        os.flush();
     }


      public void destroy() throws Exception {
      log.info("Storage service: destroy() method");
      os.close();
    writeChannel.closeFinally();
       }

       }
```

Comment: Where's **This is my servlet class**?

Comment: wil u plese give me solution for this

Comment: I am a small kid studying 8th standard. Just I know about few topics and am not even equal to you. I posted that comment in curiosity of learning how to upload file through java